# I have added Pods in .gitignore and trying to setup CI/CD with Xcode Bots. Unable to install pods through pre integration script in bot configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I have added following as pre integration script in Xcode bot to install pods in gitignore

`pod install`

The script returns following message after integration

pod: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the path to `pod install`.  For example, `/usr/local/bin/pod`

You can add this as a Add Pre-Integration Triggers when you edit your Xcode Server Bot.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# cd to where your Podfile is
cd ${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}

# add to the path, or explicitly add the path to your `pod` call
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
pod install

wait
```

Notes I found on `wait`

> The wait() function suspends execution of its calling thread until status information is available for a child process or a signal is
> received.

Comment: Notes I've been gathering on my experiences with XCS: github.com/roblabs/xcode-continuous-integration